# render FBO to an external image file

Tags: opengl

I am new to openGL and i am using Frame Buffer objects(FBO) for off- screen rendering as suggested by most of the other question's answers.

```
     GLuint fb[1],color_rb[1];
   glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, fb);
   glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fb[0]);

   glGenRenderbuffersEXT(1, color_rb);
   glBindRenderbufferEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, color_rb[0]);
   glRenderbufferStorageEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, GL_RGB, 256, 256);
   glFramebufferRenderbufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, color_rb[0]);

   // rendering to the FBO 
   glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fb[0]);
   glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

   glViewport(0, 0, 256, 256);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glOrtho(0.0, 256.0, 0.0, 256.0, -1.0, 1.0); 
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();

   glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   glDisable(GL_BLEND);
   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

   RenderATriangle();     // i have defined this function to render a texture in a triangular geometry

   GLubyte pixels[4*4*4];
   glReadPixels(0, 0, 4, 4, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

   glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
```

when i am using, i am not getting any compilation errors. i have also installed glew in my ubuntu 12.10 system. When i execute this code, segmentation fault is coming. I tried to check where is the error using cout statements and i found that error is coming in the generation of the frame buffer using glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, GLuint* array). So can anybody please tell me what's wrong with the generation of the FBO in my code. 
And one more thing, if someone can tell how to render to an external image file in disk.

My imports are:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When i execute this code, segmentation fault is coming.

On Linux anything after OpenGL-1.2 must be initialized at runtime. This is called *extension loading*. Since this task is a bit daunting if performed "manually", a number of extension loader libraries have been developed. A popular choice is [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net).

Comment: Thanks a lot ...Can you help me with a small piece of code for using GLEW and making the FBO initialisation work.??

Comment: @ChinmayJindal: You may find my minimal FBO example I wrote years ago helpful: https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/blob/master/samples/OpenGL/minimalfbo/minimalfbo.c – it contains both GLEW and FBO code.

Comment: i want to ask you one more thing...
is it possible with the help of openGL on a linux based system to generate this output without a window????

Comment: @ChinmayJindal: With current generation drivers you must create a X11 drawable on an active X server to reliably get an hardware accelerated OpenGL context. It's not required for the drawable to become visible, so you can use a hidden window. In theory most recent versions of MesaGL provide a EGL API to create HW accelerated OpenGL drawing surfaces, but the support is still experimental. You can use off screen Mesa (osmesa) in software renderer mode though. Give it another two years and there will probably widely supported APIs to create headless HW accelerated OpenGL contexts.